# how to display text in a particular span style based on the radio button selection?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          function check(){
          var button =document.getElementsByName("rdName");
          //rdName is the name of the radio buttons//
          var style =document.getElementsByName("spans");
          // spans is the name of the span tags included//
          for(var i=0; i<button.length;i++){
             if(button[i].checked == true){
                 document.getElementById(style[i].id).innerHTML ="YOU ARE:" + button[i].value;
             }
          }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <center>
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="rdName" onclick="check()" value="male"> male
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="rdName" onclick="check()" value="female">female
            // corresponding span tags for the radio buttons//
            <span id="sp1" name="spans" style="background:red"></span>
            <span id="sp2" name="spans" style="background:blue"></span>
         </center>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here i have 2 buttons and 2 span tags.
when first button is clicked i want to display the text in the first span style.
when second button is selected i need to display the text in the second span style.
This code works,but when i click the select the second radio button after i clicked the first radio button i get both text in different spans in the window.
I only want to see the particular span style for the radio button selected at a time.

Comment: >> https://javascript.info/

Answer (score 1):

Adding the else condition will help you to display the span corresponding to which the radio button was clicked. Here is the updated code. Hope it helps!

```
if(button[i].checked == true){
                 document.getElementById(style[i].id).innerHTML ="YOU ARE:" + button[i].value;
             }
// add this to your code.
else{
     document.getElementById(style[i].id).innerHTML ="";
}
```

#### Explaination

If the check for male is true, then display YOU ARE : MALE, and for the second span, set it to empty string. Incase of female do vice versa.

Comment: You're welcome!
If it helps you can upvote it so that it is helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for this as you can do it in pure CSS. In CSS you can select the input in checked state using `:chekced`. You can hide `#sp1, #sp2` on initial load then display based on checked value. Using `~` in CSS will select any siblings (adjacent or not).

```css
#sp1,
#sp2 {
  display: none;
}

input[value="male"]:checked~#sp1 {
  display: initial;
}

input[value="female"]:checked~#sp2 {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <center>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="rdName" value="male"> male
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="rdName" value="female">female // corresponding span tags for the radio buttons//
    <span id="sp1" name="spans" style="background:red">YOU ARE: male</span>
    <span id="sp2" name="spans" style="background:blue">YOU ARE: female</span>
  </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Adding 2 lines inside for worked:


for(var i=0; i<button.length;i++){
                 document.getElementById(style[i].id).style.display = "none";
                 if(button[i].checked == true){
                     document.getElementById(style[i].id).style.display = "block";
                     document.getElementById(style[i].id).innerHTML ="YOU ARE:" + button[i].value;
                 }
              }
```